# how to get each value from json in ruby sinatra?

Tags: ruby, json, sinatra

I need to extract each key-value of json and that value should save in database. but i am getting trouble in getting value of each key in json.

JSON

```
{
"topo": [
    {
        "dpid": "00:00:00:00:00:00:00:03",
        "ports": [
            3,
            1
        ]
    }
],
"app": "vm_migration"
}
```

code

```
post '/save_summary', :provides => :json do
begin
    params = JSON.parse(request.env["rack.input"].read)
    return params["topo"][0]["dpid"] 
            #above code return correct value
            return params["topo"][0]["ports"] #this is not working 
rescue Exception => e
    return e.message
end
end
```

i don't know what's wrong with ports statement, please help me to figure out small issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? The program crashes? You get an unexpected result?

Comment: right now you are returning 2 values which is not possible. return immediately returns with out processing anything further.

Comment: @toro2k no program doesn't crash. but when i used return params["topo"][0]["ports"], firebug console doesn't show response tab itself. but for return params["topo"][0]["dpid"] its show response tab with correct value.   no error also , i don't know wts wrong with dat

Comment: @engineersmnky  hey, i m telling that if i used first return statement its working but if i used next return statement its doesn't working.  i know i have to use return statement at last after all process done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are returning – `params["topo"][0]["ports"]` – is an array of two elements, which is one of the [things you can return from a Sinatra route](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Return%20Values):

> - An Array with two elements: `[status (Fixnum), response body (responds to #each)]`

So you are trying to return a response with status `3` and body `1`. The response body needs to be an object that responds to `each`, and `1` doesn’t. If you check your logs or console you will probably see an error `` undefined method `each' for 1:Fixnum ``. Assuming you just want to see the array in the browser, simply convert it to a string:

```
return params["topo"][0]["ports"].to_s
```

The first example works because `params["topo"][0]["dpid"]` is a string, and you can return strings from routes.